# Choose first occurrence and then choose the next one down

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS(Data Step) or Proc SQL, I want to choose the first occurrence of TransB based on DaysBetweenTrans first and then flag, if TransB has already been chosen then I want the next available one although I also want TransA to be unique as well i.e. TransA is a unique row and TransB is unique too.

For example, the original table looks like this:

| TransA | TransB | DaysBetweenTrans | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 4 | 1 |

but I want only:

| TransA | TransB | DaysBetweenTrans | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 4 | 1 |

I tried using sorting TransA and dedupkey and then sort TranB and dedupkey but no luck. The other way I thought of was to do first.TransA and output. Join back on the original table and remove any TransA and repeat, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Why SQL? Why not just normal SAS code?  Show what you tried and explain how it did not meet your needs.

Comment: Yeah I updated what I tried. Yup aim is SAS but thought if anyone has an SQL solution then why not. Just expanding it out there.

Comment: SQL you would want to keep any records where `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TransA ORDER BY Flag DESC, DaysBetween DESC, TransB ASC)` is `1`, if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that although TRANSB=1 is currently matched to all three values of TRANSA you want it matched to only one of them?  What does the FLAG variable have to do with it? Do you just want to exclude the records where FLAG=0?

Comment: Ha @JNevill has it right in Teradata :) just need a sas version.

Comment: Yeah I want a unique value for TransA and TransB combination but in the right order as mentioned above. And flag might not always be 1 so need to keep 0s in there.

Comment: Why did you match 1 to B instead of to A?

Comment: Because its daysinbetween and then flag=1 as priority so A and B have 1 but because of the flag=1 thats next in priority

Comment: So you want to process by TransB order and not the TransA order that you have listed the data?

Comment: So you want to sort by TRANSB DAYSBETWEENTRANS descending FLAG ?  Or is it TRANSB descending FLAG DAYSBETWEENTRANS ?

Comment: @Lorbat If this were Teradata that would be a `QUALIFY` statement. That `Row_Number()` function should work in just about any database except for like... old versions of mysql. Just have to shove it into a subquery and filter. I agree though that SAS way of doing this probably makes more sense if the data is already there.

Comment: Your explanation of the logic for how to choose is still confusing.  The first record you picked does not seem to match either posting of the data.  (PS Does everyone else find the tables stackover is generating to display this data hard to read?  It is putting so much white space to spread that data to the full width of the window it is hard to read.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into SAS procedures for optimization as a straight forward approach of taking the best next match for the current case might not find the best solution.

Here is an approach that uses a HASH to keep track of which targets have already been assigned.

It is not totally clear to me what your preference for ordering are but here is one method.  It sounds like you want to find the best match for TRANSB=1. Then for TRANSB=2, etc.

```
data have;
  input TransA $ TransB $ DaysBetweenTrans Flag;
cards;
A 1 1 0
A 2 1 1
B 1 3 1
B 2 2 1
B 3 3 1
C 1 1 1
C 3 4 1
;

proc sort data=have;
  by transB daysbetweentrans descending flag transA;
run;

data _null_;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(ordered:'Y');
    rc=h.definekey('transA');
    rc=h.definedata('transA','transB','daysbetweentrans','flag');
    rc=h.definedone();
  end;
  set have end=eof;
  by transB;
  if first.transB then found=0;
  retain found;
  if not found then if not h.add() then found=1;
  if eof then do;
    rc=h.output(dataset:'want');
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
                           Days
       Trans    Trans    Between
Obs      A        B       Trans     Flag

 1       A        2         1         1
 2       B        3         3         1
 3       C        1         1         1
```

Comment: Awesome that looks good. I had a try applying to my data but im getting "Error: Type mismatch for method parameter 1 at line 37 column 6. Error: Expecting Character Type. Error: Data Step Component Object Failure". I've converted all the columns to character but it doesnt appear to be that :( They are all numeric values.

Comment: Look at the 6th character on line 37 of the code you submitted and see what you typed.  You will notice in my answer that things like the names of the key and data variables are quoted text literals.  Most likely you forgot the quotes around the names.

Comment: Ha yeah you're right but then I found its perfect for the example but not other examples. I've updated the question to make it clearer.